# Can I force AWS CLI (v1) to use UTF encoding?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, aws-cli

**Edit: Note this is an older question, from a time when AWS CLI was `v1` - as noted in comments, there are other likely better solutions with `v2`**

I'm using AWS CLI on Windows to query items from DynamoDb.  Some of these items include non-ASCII characters.

When the query hits those items, it dies with an error

> 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'u010d' in position....

After hours of searching, I finally stumbled across a hackish workaround; under the AWSCLI\encodings directory, I copied utf_8.pyc over cp1252.pyc.  This allows me to continue, but of course is ugly.

Before resorting to that, I also tried setting environment variables such as LANG, LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE to various permutations of en-US.UTF-8 or similar, all with no effect that I could see.

Does anyone know how (or is it even possible) to tell AWS CLI to use a particular encoding?

Comment: For anyone ending up here while experiencing this issue with AWS CLI v2 on Windows in Powershell, see the following solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/664054. This question is about CLI v1, where the recommendation now is to use CLI v2 instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using the **command line** interface, a change to the terminal's encoding scheme should fix the issue.

Type:

```
chcp 65001
```

in the console (for UTF-8; you may also try different encodings) and retry your operations.

Comment: For this to work, in the AWSCLI\encodings directory I had to copy utf_8.pyc to cp65001.pyc (which didn't exist), but that's less dirty than what I had done previously.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Bless you @RookieRick, I was trying to get this to work for a couple hours until I finally came across your brilliant comment.

Comment: This option did not work for me calling `aws dynamodb scan --table-name foo --region us-east-2` on Windows 10 from a Powershell 6 session. However, @Marek's solution (see below) did.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it could help as well - the issue with translation from AWS and storing results to the file (or powershell variable):
With error:

```
aws translate translate-text --text "Investigation" --source-language-code "auto" --target-language-code "PL" >> a.txt
```

**'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015a' in position 1: character maps to**

Adding env. variable fixes the problem

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

aws translate translate-text --text "Investigation" --source-language-code "auto" --target-language-code "PL" >> a.txt
```

The same in powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\???\Documents> $aws = aws translate translate-text --text "Request" --source-language-code "auto"--target-language-code "PL"

'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u015b' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>

    PS C:\Users\???\Documents> exit

    C:\Users\???\Documents>set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

    C:\Users\???\Documents>powershell
    Windows PowerShell
    Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    PS C:\Users\???\Documents> $aws = aws translate translate-text --text "Request" --source-language-code "auto"
    --target-language-code "PL"

    PS C:\Users\???\Documents> $aws

    {
        "TranslatedText": "Prośba",
        "SourceLanguageCode": "en",
        "TargetLanguageCode": "pl"
    }
```

Comment: Tried this solution on Windows 10, and it worked. If you're setting the environment variable from a Powershell session, the syntax is `$env:PYTHONIOENCODING='UTF-16'`.

Answer (score 4):

I've reinstalled AWS CLI using [upgraded MSI installers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-windows.html#python3-msis) which now use Python 3 instead of Python 2 and the [*unknown encoding* error](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3035) is now gone.

Answer (score 3):

I am using git bash on windows 10 and set `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` was not actually did env change. Used export `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` then overcame the `charmap` error

Comment: The `cmd.exe` syntax for setting the environment variable is: `set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`; from PowerShell: `$env:PYTHONIOENCODING = 'UTF-8'`; from POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash: `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

for Windows 10 and cli is installed by python

**Error:**
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position XX-XX: character maps to

**Solution:** run following command in command-line

> set PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8