# Getting Encoding issue while fetching Alarms details by describe-alarms api aws cli

Tags: powershell, encoding, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

encountering with a strange issue while using aws cli in powershell again and again only in us-east-1 region but other region the script is working fine.

I am trying to building a logic to fetch out existing Alarms details with the help of below Script:

```
$alarmNames = aws cloudwatch --profile $profile --region $region describe-alarms --query MetricAlarms[].AlarmName[] --output json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

which is giving me a strange error i.e.

```
    aws : 
At line:525 char:15
+ ... larmNames = aws cloudwatch --profile $awsProfile --region $awsRegion  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\uf13f' in position 75: character maps to <undefined>
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid array passed in, ',' expected. (7840): [
Write-Output ( "data type is "+$alarmNames.GetType())
```

and the abobe error is pointing to me at this line but the same is working without any encoding issue in other region

> $alarmNames = aws cloudwatch --profile $profile --region $region describe-alarms --query MetricAlarms[].AlarmName[] --output json | ConvertFrom-Json

and the above query is fetching out **System.Object[]** type datatype

Any inputs or idea how should I avoid this exception/error in my powershell aws cli script ?

Answer (score 1):

**`aws.exe` is using Python behind the scenes** (as evidenced by the output from `aws.exe --version`) and the **text to be printed to stdout contains Unicode characters that cannot be encoded in the default output character encoding**
(note that the PRIVATE USE-F13F, [`U+F13F`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f13f)) character in your output is certainly unusual).

*Perhaps* the following helps:

- **Update**: it **did not help**, though the solution below  **applies to Python *in general***.

  - A solution that likely *will* help is to switch your system to using UTF-8 *system-wide*, which, however, must be carefully considered, as it has *far-reaching consequences* - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/664054).

Do the following *before* your `aws` call, from PowerShell:

- **Tell *Python* to *produce* UTF-8 output** (which by definition is capable of encoding *all* Unicode characters), by activating [Python UTF-8 Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#utf8-mode) via setting the `PYTHONUTF8` environment variable as follows (it isn't defined by default):

  ```
  $env:PYTHONUTF8=1
  ```

  - Note: This assumes that `aws.exe` honors the same environment variables as direct use of Python, and assumes that it is based on **v3.7+** of Python; for older versions, use `$env:PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8'`
    However, it is possible to invoke Python in a manner that *ignores* these environment variables, namely with `-I` or `-E`, and that is what *may* be happening behind the scenes.
    It is indeed what the *Azure* CLI, which also comes with a bundled Python version, `az` does.
- **Tell *PowerShell* to *interpret* `aws.exe` output as UTF-8-encoded**, to ensure that it is correctly decoded into .NET strings:

  ```
  [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
  ```

---

To put it all together, including saving and restoring the previous settings:

```
# Save the current settings.
$prevEnvVar = $env:PYTHONUTF8; $prevEnc = [Console]::OutputEncoding

# Tell aws.exe / Python to output UTF-8.
$env:PYTHONUTF8=1
# Tell PowerShell to interpret the output from external programs
# such as aws.exe as UTF-8.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

# Make the aws call, whose output should now be UTF-8 and which
# PowerShell should interpret as such.
$alarmNames = 
  aws cloudwatch --profile $profile --region $region describe-alarms --query MetricAlarms[].AlarmName[] --output json |
    ConvertFrom-Json

# Restore the previous settings.
$env:PYTHONUTF8 = $prevEnvVar; [Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEnc
```

Comment: I have just now checked the version of $env:PYTHONIOENCODING but find that there is no such environmental variable like this.

2) if I run this [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new() then how do I go to my previous encoding(I mean reverting context) when I am running other script like as usual ? Is it the permanent change or I have to run it after every fetching of the details of cloud-watch alarms ?

Comment: @MoneyTimes, you must _define_ the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable, namely with value `utf-8` - it doesn't exist by default. Please see my update, which also shows how to save and restore the previous settings.

Comment: I will check and update you on this, Thank you mklement0

Comment: Sorry Sir - due to some unavoidable circumstances I was not able to reach out to you, I checked and have tried with your solution but still I am getting the same error msg asI mentioned in the question - any other way out on this if you have any other tricks for this

Comment: @MoneyTimes, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39301253/45375 - but it relates to the obsolete v1 of aws; there's a v2-related comment that suggests changing the system locale to UTF-8 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/664054)), but that has far-reaching consequences.

Comment: if you have sometime to look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497402/to-get-the-instance-count-of-a-certain-period-via-launchtime-wrt-powershell